# PLS-00306 : wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SEND'

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1

I am bit stuck with this not getting how do I fix the issue

Below is my procedure written , need to send mail where I am using `Oracle APEX 20.x`

**My code :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYMAIL 
(
x_to IN varchar2,
x_frm IN varchar2,
x_sub IN varchar2,
x_bdoy IN nvarchar2 
)
AS
BEGIN
     apex_application_install.set_workspace_id(555);
     apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id => apex_application_install.get_workspace_id); 


APEX_MAIL.SEND
(
x_to => trim(x_to),
x_frm => trim(xfrm),
x_sub => x_sub,
x_body => x_body
);
APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE;
COMMIT;

END;
/
```

**ERROR :**

```
PLS-00306 : wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SEND'
```

Any fix for this is appreciated

Comment: Your `x_body` (or `x_bdoy`?) appears to be `nvarchar2` instead of `varchar2`, which might cause problems. But are you really doing `x_to => ...` etc instead of `p_to => ...` [to match the procedure declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/SEND-Procedure-Signature-1.html#GUID-B1CD726B-EABE-4A9D-A7A4-3A973E84262D)? As you seem to have retyped this for the question instead of pasting your real code it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/SEND-Procedure-Signature-2.html#GUID-579D3770-3164-42C9-8EDD-69A61CB3207C) for the `APEX_MAIL` api has the signature for the `SEND` procedure.

It shows (copied this from "31.10 SEND Procedure Signature 1")

```
APEX_MAIL.SEND(
    p_to                IN    VARCHAR2,
    p_from              IN    VARCHAR2,
    p_body              IN  [ VARCHAR2 | CLOB ],
    p_body_html         IN  [ VARCHAR2 | CLOB ] DEFAULT NULL,
    p_subj              IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_cc                IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_bcc               IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_replyto           IN    VARCHAR2);
```

In your code you're invoking `APEX_MAIL.SEND` with arguments `x_to , x_frm ,x_sub ,x_body`. That won't work. The exact argument names need to be used and the variables that are passed in as values need to have matching data types